# What is Tcl lindex order of complexity?

Tags: list, tcl, time-complexity

I was under the impression that Tcl looks at its' data as lists, not arrays, when using lindex.
Terefore, order of searching of the nth element is O(n), since "everything is a string". I have found empirically, in several testcases, which I cannot share, that it is not.
The lindex acted closer to O( log(n) ), or even lower complexity than that!.
Is that intended, or "pure luck"?

Comment: `lindex` is O(1) because of caching. `lsearch` is usually O(n), but can be run as `lsearch -sorted` which is O(logn) provided you've sorted the list first.

Comment: Thanks.
Isn't caching limited by memory, for very large lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tcl lists are C arrays under the hood, so you should see O(1) for indexed access. There is no built in linked list structure in Tcl (only in extensions).

You might see a higher complexity if there is shimmering (e.g. when you have a string representation that needs to be converted internally and parsed into a list before being used). For pure lists without a string representation (like the ones you get from `[list 1 2 3]` it should be O(1).

There is a historical dimension to this. If you use an ancient Tcl like Tcl 7, that does not cache lists in internal objects, but reparses the string representation, you will see the expected `O(N)` performance for item access. But for any modern Tcl that uses `Tcl_Obj` internally, this is no longer the case (unless you force it by shimmering to and from string all the time).

Comment: There are a few places where linked lists are used inside Tcl's implementation, but they're not exposed to scripts as linked lists.